# Need suggestions for developing Scrabble like game in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I want to develop a game like Scrabble in WPF for which I need some suggestions

For Visuals:
1. What controls can be utilized to represent a (let's say 9 x 9) matrix? I would need ability to associate each cell with an id to know its state at all times during execution.

2. How can I inject different visual properties to a cell of matrix?
3. Would I need something like separate layers for base board, and tiles?

For logic:
4. How to go about validating a word and possible words around it?

Please advise. Thanks
PJ

Comment: take a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/mharsh/archive/2007/01/28/wpf-e-scrabble-tiles.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is a complete solution on CodePlex here: [Scrabble for WPF](http://wpfscrabble.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a Reversi game on Codeplex at http://correspondence.codeplex.com. I used triggers to data bind properties of a square to styles of a cell. The same technique should work for scrabble.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building your Custom Layout manager.

All you need to do is override the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods:

```
public class ScrabblePanel : Panel
{
  protected override Size MeasureOverride( Size availableSize ) 
  {
     // your code here
  }

  protected override Size ArrangeOverride( Size finalSize ) {}
  {
     // your code here
  }
}
```